# Where to get managed object context in NSPersistentDocument?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentdocument

It seems there's spotty information out there for using Core-data with Document based apps. I have a window controller that runs a modal window in the current document. The user enters data into a text field, which creates a mutable array of strings, which I want to use to create model objects (for a many-to-many relationship), and then save them to the core-data stack. This is the  method I have in the modal window's controller.

```
 - (IBAction)saveContext:(id)sender {

if ([tagsArray count] != 0) {
    int objectcount;
    for (objectcount = 0; objectcount < [tagsArray count]; objectcount ++){
        Tag *singleTag = (Tag *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        singleTag.tagname = [tagsArray objectAtIndex:objectcount];
        singleTag.video = selectedFile;
        NSLog(@"Tagnames %@",singleTag.tagname);
        
    }
}
[NSApp stopModalWithCode:NSOKButton];
[self.window close];
}
```

Ok the compiler isn't happy with self.managedObjectContext. Understandably so, since this class doesn't have a context. The way I understand it, with a document based app you want to use only one MOC. What I don't understand is how to access the document's MOC. Apple's docs are a little unclear.

> Getting a Managed Object Context
>
> In OS X:
>
> In an single-coordinator applications, you can get the application’s context directly from             the application delegate.
>
> **In document-based applications, you can get the context directly from the document instance.**

I'm embarrassed to say I don't know what this means. How do I get the context from the document instance? Is it some sort of global variable? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your Modal Window pass it the documents `managedObjectContext` to use.

So maybe have a property in the controller class for the modal window and set that `modalWindow.moc=self.managedObjectContext` prior to calling `modalWindow.show` or whatever you are using.  Assuming `self` is your NSPersistentDocument subclass.

You must used the documents existing MOC, don't create a new one (you can but you don't want to go there).

The documents MOC is your definitive access point for adding objects to your Core Data store.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply/acknowledgement. This nailed it! I figured it would be something incredibly simple I had overlooked. Newb fail. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

`NSPersistentDocument` has a `managedObjectContext` method to get its managed object context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [yourPersistentDocument managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What exactly is supposed to go in the "yourPersistentDocument" part? I assumed it would be "Document", referencing my Document.m class, which is the NSPersistentDocument sublcass xcode automatically generated for me when I started this project. I'm getting a compiler warning "No known class method for selector 'managedObjectContext'".

Comment: @Joseph: Strange, the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPersistentDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentDocument/managedObjectContext) says that NSPersistentDocument has a managedObjectContext method.

Comment: so Document would be correct then? I couldn't imagine what else it would be. Should I simply create a MOC just for this class? Or does it require you to only use the one provided?

Comment: @Joseph: Your document (which inherits from NSPersistentDocument) should respond to that method, and you should use the provided context. But I am not at my computer currently, so I can not test it myself right now.

Comment: @JosephToronto: I have create a "Document-Based Application" in Xcode with the "Use Core Data" option. `NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext]` worked without problems inside the Xcode generated Document class.

Comment: Yes, within the Document class it works fine, but I'm trying to create a MOC from a view controller.

Comment: @JosephToronto: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. If you need a MOC tied to the document, you have to pass the document (or its context) to that view controller.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35696/discussion-between-joseph-toronto-and-martin-r)